# Fullcalendar - Logic to show events' color in a gradiant way

Tags: php, css, fullcalendar

I will use Fullcalendar as a booking calendar , and i want the day's background to be gradiant from green to red in function of how much places are booked that day (Max 30).
(Line 252 to 259 are used for changing the cell color)

```
$count = 0;
            $steps = 15;
            if ($donnees['entries'] < 16 )
            $Gradients = Gradient("00ff80", "ffff00", $steps);
            else
            $Gradients = Gradient("ffff00", "FF0000", $steps);
            $valel = intval($steps-$donnees['entries']);
            $color = '#'.$Gradients[$valel];
```

The calendar won't show up because my logic doesn't work for a certain reason.
Please remove the line 258.

```
$valel = intval($steps);
```

And change this line after it with this if you wanna the calendar show up.

```
$color = '#'.$Gradients[$steps-2];
```

(The function Gradient allow me to make the gradient effect)

code :

```
    <?php
require_once('bdd.php');


$sql = "SELECT id, title, start, end, color FROM events ";

$req = $bdd->prepare($sql);
$req->execute();

$events = $req->fetchAll();

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">

    <title>Bare - Start Bootstrap Template</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap Core CSS -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- FullCalendar -->
    <link href='css/fullcalendar.css' rel='stylesheet' />


    <!-- Custom CSS -->
    <style>
    .fc-time
    {
        display : none;
    }
    .fc-start
    {
        height:500px;
        weith:50px;
    }
    body {
        padding-top: 70px;
        /* Required padding for .navbar-fixed-top. Remove if using .navbar-static-top. Change if height of navigation changes. */
    }
    #calendar {
        max-width: 800px;
    }
    .col-centered{
        float: none;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }
    #color
    {
        display:none
    }
    </style>

    <!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->

</head>

<body>
    <?php
                    function Gradient($HexFrom, $HexTo, $ColorSteps) {
                  $FromRGB['r'] = hexdec(substr($HexFrom, 0, 2));
                  $FromRGB['g'] = hexdec(substr($HexFrom, 2, 2));
                  $FromRGB['b'] = hexdec(substr($HexFrom, 4, 2));

                  $ToRGB['r'] = hexdec(substr($HexTo, 0, 2));
                  $ToRGB['g'] = hexdec(substr($HexTo, 2, 2));
                  $ToRGB['b'] = hexdec(substr($HexTo, 4, 2));

                  $StepRGB['r'] = ($FromRGB['r'] - $ToRGB['r']) / ($ColorSteps - 1);
                  $StepRGB['g'] = ($FromRGB['g'] - $ToRGB['g']) / ($ColorSteps - 1);
                  $StepRGB['b'] = ($FromRGB['b'] - $ToRGB['b']) / ($ColorSteps - 1);

                  $GradientColors = array();

                  for($i = 0; $i <= $ColorSteps; $i++) {
                    $RGB['r'] = floor($FromRGB['r'] - ($StepRGB['r'] * $i));
                    $RGB['g'] = floor($FromRGB['g'] - ($StepRGB['g'] * $i));
                    $RGB['b'] = floor($FromRGB['b'] - ($StepRGB['b'] * $i));

                    $HexRGB['r'] = sprintf('%02x', ($RGB['r']));
                    $HexRGB['g'] = sprintf('%02x', ($RGB['g']));
                    $HexRGB['b'] = sprintf('%02x', ($RGB['b']));

                    $GradientColors[] = implode(NULL, $HexRGB);
                  }
                  $GradientColors = array_filter($GradientColors, "len");
                  return $GradientColors;
                }

                function len($val){
                  return (strlen($val) == 6 ? true : false );
                }
    ?>
    <!-- Navigation -->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
        <div class="container">
            <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Free Calendar</a>
            </div>
            <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Menu</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
        </div>
        <!-- /.container -->
    </nav>



    <!-- jQuery Version 1.11.1 -->
    <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>

    <!-- Bootstrap Core JavaScript -->
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <!-- FullCalendar -->
    <script src='js/moment.min.js'></script>
    <script src='js/fullcalendar.min.js'></script>

    <script>

    $(document).ready(function() {

        $('#calendar').fullCalendar({

            header: {
                left: 'prev,next today',
                center: 'title',
                right: 'month,basicWeek,basicDay'
            },
            defaultDate: '2017-09-01',
            editable: true,
            eventLimit: true, // allow "more" link when too many events
            selectable: true,
            selectHelper: true,
            disableDragging: true,
            select: function(start, end) {

                $('#ModalAdd #start').val(moment(start).format('YYYY-MM-DD'));
                $('#ModalAdd #end').val(moment(end).format('YYYY-MM-DD'));
                $date_click = new Date(moment(start).format('YYYY-MM-DD'));
                $firstdate = new Date('2017 Sep 20');
                $lastdate = new Date('2017 Sep 24');
                $vari1 = $firstdate.getTime().toString();
                $vari3 = $lastdate.getTime().toString();

                $varilala = $vari1.substring(0, 5);
                $variloco = $vari3.substring(0, 5);

                $vari2 = $date_click.getTime().toString();
                $varilolo = $vari2.substring(0, 5);


                $varibel = moment(start).format('YYYY-MM-DD');

                if ($varilolo < $varilala || $varilolo > $variloco || $varibel == '2017-09-25')
                    alert("You can't select this day !!");
                else
                $('#ModalAdd').modal('show');
            },
            eventRender: function(event, element) {
                element.bind('dblclick', function() {
                    $('#ModalEdit #id').val(event.id);
                    $('#ModalEdit #title').val(event.title);
                    $('#ModalEdit #color').val(event.color);
                    $('#ModalEdit').modal('show');
                });
            },
            eventDrop: function(event, delta, revertFunc) { // si changement de position

                edit(event);

            },
            eventResize: function(event,dayDelta,minuteDelta,revertFunc) { // si changement de longueur

                edit(event);

            },
        dayClick: function(date, jsEvent, view) {

        alert(date.format());

        },
            events: [
            <?php foreach($events as $event): 

                $start = explode(" ", $event['start']);
                $end = explode(" ", $event['end']);
                if($start[1] == '00:00'){
                    $start = $start[0];
                }else{
                    $start = $start[0];
                }
                if($end[1] == '00:00'){
                    $end = $end[0];
                }else{
                    $end = $event['end'];
                }


                $mareq = $bdd->prepare('SELECT COUNT(start) AS entries FROM events WHERE start LIKE "'.$start.'%"');
                $mareq->execute();
                $donnees = $mareq->fetch();

                /*if($donnees['entries'] < 8)
                {
                    $color = '#00FF80';
                }
                else
                {
                    if($donnees['entries'] > 8)
                    $color = '#C5FD4A';

                    if($donnees['entries'] > 15)
                    $color = '#FFFF00';

                    if($donnees['entries'] > 25)
                    $color = '#FF8000';

                    if($donnees['entries'] == 30)
                    $color = '#FF0000';

                }
                */


                $count = 0;
                $steps = 15;
                if ($donnees['entries'] < 16 )
                $Gradients = Gradient("00ff80", "ffff00", $steps);
                else
                $Gradients = Gradient("ffff00", "FF0000", $steps);
                $valel = intval($steps-$donnees['entries']);
                $color = '#'.$Gradients[$valel];
            ?>
                {
                    id: '<?php echo $event['id']; ?>',
                    title: '<?php echo ' Il reste '. (30-$donnees['entries']) .'/30 places.'; ?>',
                    start: '<?php echo $start; ?>',
                    end: '<?php echo $end; ?>',
                    color: '<?php echo $color; ?>',
                    borderColor: '<?php echo $event['color']; ?>',
                },
            <?php endforeach; ?>
            ]


        });

        function edit(event){
            start = event.start.format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm');
            if(event.end){
                end = event.end.format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm');
            }else{
                end = start;
            }

            id =  event.id;

            Event = [];
            Event[0] = id;
            Event[1] = start;
            Event[2] = end;

            $.ajax({
             url: 'editEventDate.php',
             type: "POST",
             data: {Event:Event},
             success: function(rep) {
                    if(rep == 'OK'){
                        alert('Saved');
                    }else{
                        alert('Could not be saved. try again.'); 
                    }
                }
            });
        }

    });

</script>
    <!-- Page Content -->
    <div class="container">

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12 text-center">
                <h1>FullCalendar BS3 PHP MySQL</h1>
                <p class="lead">Complete with pre-defined file paths that you won't have to change!</p>
                <div id="calendar" class="col-centered">
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
        <!-- /.row -->

        <!-- Modal -->
        <div class="modal fade" id="ModalAdd" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
          <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
            <form class="form-horizontal" method="POST" action="addEvent.php">

              <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Add Event</h4>
              </div>
              <div class="modal-body">

                  <div class="form-group">

                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                      <input type="hidden" name="title" class="form-control" id="title" placeholder="Title" value="">
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                      <select name="color" class="form-control" id="color">
                          <option value="">Choose</option>
                          <option style="color:#0071c5;" value="#0071c5">&#9724; Dark blue</option>
                          <option style="color:#40E0D0;" value="#40E0D0">&#9724; Turquoise</option>
                          <option selected="selected" style="color:#008000;" value="#008000">&#9724; Green</option>                       
                          <option style="color:#FFD700;" value="#FFD700">&#9724; Yellow</option>
                          <option style="color:#FF8C00;" value="#FF8C00">&#9724; Orange</option>
                          <option style="color:#FF0000;" value="#FF0000">&#9724; Red</option>
                          <option style="color:#000;" value="#000">&#9724; Black</option>

                        </select>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="start" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Start date</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                      <input type="text" name="start" class="form-control" id="start" readonly>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                  <?php
                      echo '<script src="js/demo_defer.js" defer></script>';
                      ?>
                    <label for="start_2" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Choose time</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-10">

                      <select name="start_2" class="form-control" id="start_2">



                      <?php

                            for($i=7;$i<22;$i++)
                            {
                                if($i < 10)
                                {
                                echo '<option value="0'.$i.':00">0'.$i.':00</option>';
                                echo '<option value="0'.$i.':30">0'.$i.':30</option>';
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                echo '<option value="'.$i.':00">'.$i.':00</option>';
                                echo '<option value="'.$i.':30">'.$i.':30</option>';
                                }

                            }
                      ?>
                      </select>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                      <input type="hidden" name="end" class="form-control" id="end" readonly>
                    </div>
                  </div>



              </div>
              <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
              </div>
            </form>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>



        <!-- Modal -->
        <div class="modal fade" id="ModalEdit" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
          <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
            <form class="form-horizontal" method="POST" action="editEventTitle.php">
              <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Edit Event</h4>
              </div>
              <div class="modal-body">

                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="title" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Title</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                      <input type="text" name="title" class="form-control" id="title" placeholder="Title">
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="color" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Color</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                      <select name="color" class="form-control" id="color">
                          <option value="">Choose</option>
                          <option style="color:#0071c5;" value="#0071c5">&#9724; Dark blue</option>
                          <option style="color:#40E0D0;" value="#40E0D0">&#9724; Turquoise</option>
                          <option style="color:#008000;" value="#008000">&#9724; Green</option>                       
                          <option style="color:#FFD700;" value="#FFD700">&#9724; Yellow</option>
                          <option style="color:#FF8C00;" value="#FF8C00">&#9724; Orange</option>
                          <option style="color:#FF0000;" value="#FF0000">&#9724; Red</option>
                          <option style="color:#000;" value="#000">&#9724; Black</option>

                        </select>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div id="starto">
                  </div>
                    <div class="form-group"> 
                        <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
                          <div class="checkbox">
                            <label class="text-danger"><input type="checkbox"  name="delete"> Delete event</label>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                  <input type="hidden" name="id" class="form-control" id="id">


              </div>
              <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
              </div>
            </form>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

    </div>
    <!-- /.container -->
</body>

</html>
```

Sorry if the code is long but i wanted you to see the big picture.
If you want any explication of a part of the code please write it in the comments and i will answer you.
P.S : link to the [database](https://www.mediafire.com/?q5z1qu1mtylakhz) if needed.

Edit 1 : Here is the part of code responsible for the color change :

```
            $count = 0;
        $steps = 15;
        if ($donnees['entries'] < 16 )
        $Gradients = Gradient("00ff80", "ffff00", $steps);
        else
        $Gradients = Gradient("ffff00", "FF0000", $steps);
        if($donnees['entries'] != 30)
        $valel = intval($steps-$donnees['entries']);
    else
        $valel = intval($steps);
         if ($valel <= 0)
             $valel=5;
         if($valel >= 15)
             $valel=5;
        $color = '#'.$Gradients[$valel-5];
```

It worked quite nice for the half max (15) reservations per day and after that when i add another reservation , i got some error regarding html auto generation before some events js code and after it , i have a 
 , code source view for that part : https://pastebin.com/FExewb0r

Comment: to save us some time, what's the difference in output between the two pieces of code you mentioned? Presumably, one of them produces an invalid hex value? What value did you expect it to produce? No-one can work this out for you, because we're missing a required input value (the value of `$donnees['entries']` in the case that causes the problem)

Comment: $donnees['entries'] is the number of reservations made in a certain day.I The function gradient return an array of hex values i type Gradient[the steps - the number of reservations made in a certain day] which will give me for exemple Gradient[3] which is a hex value.

Comment: and in the situation where you say it doesn't work, what's the output you get? Presumably something invalid? or it errors? And what input did you give it to get that? Does it always fail no matter what the input, or only when given certain values? What output value were you expecting instead? I asked all of this before but you haven't answered yet.

Comment: The calender doesn't show , and i tried to echo an alert of the value of  $valel = intval($steps-$donnees['entries']); And surprisely it showed resonable numbers , and i want that value to be the option of my function so i can get every time a different color , so it would be $color = '#'.$Gradients[$valel];

Comment: yes but _what_ numbers? "Reasonable" isn't a concept in computing. It's either correct or it isn't. Is it the value you expected from the calculation? Is it a valid hex value? Does it result in valid JSON for the event feed? Have you checked your browser console for errors when the calendar doesn't show? It would seem that it maybe outputs something which cannot be understood by the browser.

Comment: Since it's php inside js it will tell you that you have an error but it won't give you the code line of error or any other informations. When i say a  number i mean an int , and this int i want it to put it as  an array option forget about hexa values , this is just an int , and i don't know what the problem is about this int , the values are correct.

Comment: if you want to make it say `color:#...` in the event markup the value after the # must be a hex value not an int. And PHP will give you an error line if the PHP fails. JS will give you an error line (in the browser console) if that fails. I don't understand why you won't tell me what value `$Gradients[$valel]` outputs. It's quite a simple question.

Comment: The output is a correct hexa color value . it give me the js error and line , but types "Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token" for a <br /> that i don't know why the code generate it.   exemple :   id: '23',
     title: ' Il reste 29/30 places.',
     start: '2017-09-15',
     end: '2017-09-15 01:00:00',
     color: '#a3ff2d',
     borderColor: '#008000',
    },
   <br />

Comment: does this happen for all the events? Or just this one example? And it goes away if you change the code to `$color = '#'.$Gradients[$steps-2];` as you mentioned above?

Comment: https://pastebin.com/FExewb0r part of code source of the page , some cells have the perfect hexa value but others have just a '#' with a generated html before and a <br /> after . i will edit the post and add the part of code i changed

Comment: I noticed that the reason why it generate the error is because tha $valel value is negative

Comment: it seems to be printing a debug error, presumably due to your debug settings, it must be setting the value of the variable to the debug output HTML, which normally would perhaps go into a separate page. And the error is that there's no element in your Gradients array with an index of -6. So you need to fix whatever is making $valel have an unacceptable value, or perhaps reset it to 0 if it goes below 0, or something. Depends what the gradients array contains.

Comment: Did that , still doesn't work . some get fixed and some which was good become broken ...

Comment: sounds like your gradient logic is wrong then maybe.

Comment: It's not "maybe" , i think it is 100 % wrong that's why i need help with ideas lol

Comment: Ok so now we narrowed down the problem, i suggest we ditch all the other irrelevant stuff from the question, edit it to just focus on the gradient function and the code which interacts directly with it. The fact you want to make a calendar afterwards isn't really all that important (you can mention it as context, but no need really to include the calendar code, because that isn't the root of the problem).

Comment: The gradient function is clearly relatively complex and maths-y, so you will need to lay out very clearly your expectations, like a set of requirements, and illustrate it with some test cases, especially focussing on the cases where it doesn't work - in terms of what range of values the function should be able to accept and what it should output, vs what you actually get currently.